# Bootstrap .dropdown li background color

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my site: http://defend-foreclosure.com/index.html

I can't get the list items in the dropdown for "law" to change any color but blue when I hover over them. Can anyone tell me what element in the CSS I need to edit? I've been testing all sorts of elements in both bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css with no luck.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Don't change bootstrap.css. Create another css file where you can override this.
Anyway, the line is 4572:

```
.dropdown-menu li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu li > a:focus, .dropdown-submenu:hover > a
```

Set background-image to none, and background-color to whatever color you want.

Comment: Never thought that it was an image :'(

Comment: I found that just setting background-color: #fff and background-image: none didn't work for me. I'm not sure why, but (using LESS) I set the background-image to "linear-gradient(#fff, #fff)" and that did the trick. I wonder if the -o, -moz, -webkit vendor prefixes were getting left behind (or maybe stuck in Chrome's cache somehow).

Comment: And to make it work with older versions of **IE**, don't forget to add `filter: none;`. Awesome answer, by the way. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this:.dropdown-menu li.changeColorOnHover > a:hover, .dropdown-menu li.changeColorOnHover > a:focus{
 background-color: @white-color; 
 background-image : "linear-gradient(#fff, #fff)";
}

Comment: @Smitha If you create a new question, showing your HTML and CSS, I'm sure you'll get an answer really fast.

Comment: hats-off sir.you rock!

Answer (score 6):

If you also intend to change the color of a selected element, you should take care of the active class of the li element:

```
.dropdown-menu li.active > a,
.dropdown-menu li.active > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu li.active > a:focus {
    ...
}
```