# Changing the background for bootstrap dropdown a on hover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap's dropdown from a navigation div, and I'd like to change the color of the the **sub-menu** links on hover. Nothing I'm attempting works, and I can't make sense of it. It's not having any effect even when trying to run things from the chrome console.

I have created a css file where I override the defaults. The background change for normal `a` tags work, but the hover doesn't. Why is that? I also tried affecting the `li` and using `!important`, but none of that is having any effect.

I'm using Bootstrap 3.1.1. Here's my css:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: white; /* This has an effect */
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
    background-color: red; /* This doesn't... why? */
}
```

And check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sW7Dh/) too for a demonstration (for some reason you need to drag the result panel a whole lot to the left before you see the button). Any ideas?

**edit**

Note I am trying to change the background color for the links **in** the dropdown, not for the main button which is `MyProfile`.

Comment: Also, this isn't a duplicate. I have tried [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250723/twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-submenu-background-color) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487707/bootstrap-dropdown-li-background-color), and nothing works.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Bootstrap [defines a background image](https://www.karltarvas.com/2018/02/14/bootstrap-change-dropdown-item-background-on-hover.html) for the elements to override some clashes in their media queries. Remove the image to use a simple fill color.

You can redefine your hover as follows:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sW7Dh/4/

Comment: Almost, only I want the submenu hover to work, not the `MyProfile`. Notice how I use `.dropdown-menu`. The weird thing is, using `!important` doesn't work...

Comment: Yes! Thank you! That works. Wow, I haven't thought they were doing something so convoluted as using a background image instead of a normal background-color... That's so weird!

Comment: For future reference if you're having a hard time identifying the problem with hovering elements, simply use the Chrome dev tools which allow you to inspect elements with pseudo classes attached: http://i.imgur.com/NzV8E2E.png

Comment: I am using the chrome dev tools, but I guess I missed that

Comment: Thank you so much. I have to echo @yuvi, I'm surprised - any thoughts on why they would have chosen to take that route? I don't see an advantage offhand. For me, Chrome Developer Tools wasn't letting me freeze the dropdown menu in order to inspect it in that state.

Comment: @Bemisawa [because of this issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14381)

Comment: In newer version of bootstrap, there is no longer a background image for that.
In case you use SCSS, you can override the Variables like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52120982/14331711).