# How to Change the Background Color and Text Color of Bootstrap Navbar Dropdown-menu List Items After Menu Collapses

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

New to Bootstrap and creating a basic navigation bar. I am hoping that what I need makes sense. Put simply, I need the background color and text color of list items in the dropdown-menu to match both before and after they collapse. I cannot seem to find the right CSS attributes to edit, and the many combinations that I have tried do not solve my problem. [A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074956/bootstrap-dropdown-menu-text-color) did not solve my problem, but perhaps it is worth looking at for others.

Below is what the menu looks like before it collapses. Each `<li>` has a link, or `<a>`, within it (see basic HTML below). The text color is black, and the background color is white. When the item is hovered over, the background of `<li>` turns tan. I want the same colors after the menu collapses:

[image: Pre-Collapse]

After collapse it appears like this:

[image: Post-Collapse]

The colors seem to change back to Bootstrap's defaults after collapsing. I would like the text for **Sub 1** and **Sub 3** to be black by default with a white background, while keeping the color behind the header, **Stuff 2**, the same. The colors seem to work fine when clicked or hovered over (tan background with black font).

Below is some of the relevant HTML and CSS. I know that some of it is messy (and that the use of `!important;` is often considered poor form), but I hope someone out there can help me identify the block of code so I can get it working and then focus on cleaning it up.

**Basic HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div id="navbarbg" class="container-fluid">
    <div id="rbgnavbar" class="container">    
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
          </button>
          <a id="logo" class="pull-left" href="http://www.redbuttegarden.org"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Red Butte Garden"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="rbgwhitelink">STUFF 1 <span class="caret"></span></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="rbgwhitelink">STUFF 2 <span class="caret"></span></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="rbgwhitelink">STUFF 3 <span class="caret"></span></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Basic CSS:**

```
#rbgnavbar a:hover, a, li, .dropdown-menu li:hover {
    color: #000000;
}

.dropdown-menu li:hover {
    background-color: #F2EDE4;
    color: #000000;
}

/* Main dropdown menu items change cover when selected/clicked */
.dropdown-toggle:active, .open .dropdown-toggle, .dropdown:hover {
    background-color: #196143 !important;
}

.dropdown-menu li, .dropdown-menu a {
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
}

.dropdown {
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#rbgnavbar {
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#00502F;
}


.rbgwhitelink {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.dropdown ul {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* Border thickness and color between dropdown menu li, padding */
.dropdown-menu li {
    border-top: 2px double #D3D3D3;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

/* Background color of li in navbar when hovered over */
.dropdown-menu li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu li > a:focus, .dropdown-submenu:hover > a, .dropdown-menu li:hover {
    background-color: #F2EDE4;
}

/* Makes dropdown-menu li links bold*/
.dropdown-menu li > a, .dropdown-menu li > a:visited {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Looks black to me: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/a7zn48d4/ try forking it

Comment: Ah, I took out a bit too much of the CSS. Just added back the #rbgnavbar so the bg looks green again. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use media queries and add the classes you want to tweak.
For example:

```
/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
  .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
    }
```

For Bootstrap 3 default media queries you may found it [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries)

Comment: This was immensely helpful. I updated my code accordingly, and it behaves much better now.

Comment: Good to hear. Keep coding.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting, this did it:

```
.dropdown-menu li {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.dropdown-menu li:hover {
    background-color: #F2EDE4;
}

.dropdown-menu li > a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Changes the color of link text <a> after navbar has collapsed for small screen or mobile mode */
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:visited {
    color: #000000; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to change this color:

```
.dropdown-toggle:active, .open .dropdown-toggle, .dropdown:hover {
    background-color: #196143 !important;
}
```