# How to change bootstrap 4 drop-down colors?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to change both the background, and font color of the bootstrap 4 dropdown navigation.

I tried to use

```
.nav.nav-tabs > li.dropdown.active.open > a, 
.nav.nav-tabs > li.dropdown.active.open > ul.dropdown-menu a:hover,
.nav.nav-tabs > li.dropdown.open > a, 
.nav.nav-tabs > li.dropdown.open > ul.dropdown-menu a:hover
{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #b91773;
  border-color: #fff;
}
```

But this wasn't working too well for me. Here is my HTML:

```
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded="false">
  Dropdown link
</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```css
.dropdown {list-style: none; background: green; padding: 10px; display: inline-block;}
.dropdown .nav-link {color:#fff; text-decoration: none;}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu a{color: #000; text-decoration: none;}
.dropdown .btn {background: green; color:#fff;}
.dropdown .btn:hover {background: cyan; color:#000;}
.dropdown .btn:active {background: cyan; color:#000;}
.dropdown .btn:focus {background: cyan; color:#000;}
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {display: inline-block; width: 100%; padding: 10px 5px;}
.container .dropdown .dropdown-menu a:hover
{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #b91773;
  border-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded="false">
  Dropdown link
</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is a some code, hope it will helps you.

**Edited**

It is working fine now

Comment: Hey man, I'm actually using bootstrap 4, I should of clarified that. This is great, except it does not work for version 4

Comment: @Temple Please check it is working fine now with bootstrap 4, you should properly override the css else it will not work. and have you used tether.js ?

Answer (score 23):

I know this is already answered, but since I'm bookmarking it, I want to give the solution that worked for me when [theming Bootsrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/) using Sass and NPM.

Note that I include functions and variables above my custom ones because I need to access them otherwise the compilation will fail. [Read more about it on this issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/22891#issuecomment-344893715).

Suppose you have your `_custom.scss` like this:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";

// Add your custom variables here

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Then you can go to [Bootstrap's main variables file](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss#L598-L620) and copy over the ones you want to overwrite.

For example, if I want my dropdown background to be dark with white links I'd do it like:

```
$dropdown-bg:                       $dark;
$dropdown-link-color:               $light;
```

And my `_custom.scss` file after the changes would like like this:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";

// Add your custom variables here
$dropdown-bg:                       $dark;
$dropdown-link-color:               $light;

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

And this is an image of what it looks like after compiling Sass:

[image: Bootstrap's dropdown with dark background]

This way I don't overwrite CSS rules avoiding unnecessary clutter.

Comment: Great answer. I additionally edited `$dropdown-link-active-bg` and  `$dropdown-link-hover-bg`.

Answer (score 1):

In `Bootstrap v4.3.1` I simply copy the `CSS path` from the browser `developer tools`, and add it to my `Website.css`, and add to it some styles to much the look and feel of the website I am building:

```
/*drop-down override*/
div.btn-group.show div.dropdown-menu.show {
  background-color: #4b4b4b;
}

div.btn-group.show div.dropdown-menu.show button.dropdown-item {
  color: #e1e1e1;
}

div.btn-group.show div.dropdown-menu.show div.dropdown-divider {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.9);
}

div.btn-group.show div.dropdown-menu.show button.dropdown-item:hover,
div.btn-group.show div.dropdown-menu.show button.dropdown-item:focus {
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

The result should look like this:

[image: Output dropdown menu]

Comment: I'm using *exactly* Bootstrap version 4.3.1 and this isn't working for me for nav item dropdowns. But thanks for sharing :-)

Comment: You may need to remove `div.` or replace `div.` with `a.` or `ul.` depending how you built the menu.

Comment: Because of the changes in the new Bootstrap version 4, I just wanted to draw attention to that all what you need to do is choosing the active selector, with fully qualified order like in the answer, it not a problem of `div` or what element you use, it is just knowing the qualified selector.