# How to change the DropdownToggle background color when click DropdownItem list in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I am trying to change the background colour of DropdownToggle when clicking DropdownItem. Also, change the top and bottom blue border(not sure)? when click the DropdownToggle

[Picture 1: This is the picture that before I click the item such as "AK","CA","DE"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NY1Q.jpg)

When I click the dropdown item "FL" in this case, the background colour change to black, and there are top and bottom blue border around the "FL"

[Picture 2: after select(click) "FL"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVG6D.jpg)

How to change the DropdownToggle background colour when I click the item, i don't want black like the picture, and also try to remove the blue border.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ I have tidied up your existing question but you should also add the pertinent code so that SO contributors can better help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change bootstrap 4 drop-down colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612813/how-to-change-bootstrap-4-drop-down-colors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your code added to the question I'm not able to be more specific, but you can access the elements in your `nav` with the following Bootstrap elements

CSS

```
.nav-item {}

.nav-item a {}

.nav-item a:hover {}

.nav-item .dropdown-item {}
```

Because you are over-riding Bootstrap CSS you will likely need to add `!important;` to the attributes that you change.